# Last 3 digits always zero when generating 15-digit random number

Tags: java, random

I wanted to generate a random number between `1_000_0000_0000_000` and `9_999_9999_9999_999L`using Java so I used the following code,

```
final long MAX_NUMBER = 9_999_9999_9999_999L;
final long MIN_NUMBER = 1_000_0000_0000_000L;
System.out.print(Long.valueOf(new Random().nextLong() * 
                     (MAX_NUMBER - MIN_NUMBER)));
```

The problem with the code is, the code does generate 15 digit random number, but the last 3-digits are always zero, and some time it generates negative number.

Can anybody tell me why the last 3-digits are always zero ?

Here are some of the outputs,

`7160629848698886104000`

`-6581075034034719564000`

`6645937379553681443000`

`6363833355925386903000`

Comment: Code works fine for me. I don't get 3 zeros at the end. What Random are you importing?

Comment: I am importing `import java.util.Random`

Comment: Agreed with @Hayden.
Outputs: 
`3975621119110322698`
`9168405849564378394`
`-7822944210852808832`

Comment: Are you running a 32 bit or 64 bit operating system? I don't know if it is relevant, but is good to cover all cases.

Comment: I am running 64-bit Windows 7, and using AMD processor.

Comment: What JVM do you use?

Comment: one that installed by default. I am using JRE1.7

Comment: The 1, 3, 4, 4, 3 digit grouping is curious but not formally wrong.  Does the fact that you are getting 22-digit outputs instead of 15-digit outputs not suggest that there is trouble quite separate from the trailing zeros issues?

Comment: Are you printing anything else in your program? I notice you use `print` and not `println`. It could be that you later on `println` 000 which will be appended to your previous `print`

Answer (score 3):

`nextLong()` may return any long value, which include negative values. Multiplying the result of `nextLong()` by `(MAX_NUMBER - MIN_NUMBER)` may cause an overflow and will not give you a result in the required range.

You can use `Math.random()` instead :

```
System.out.print((long)(Math.random() * (MAX_NUMBER - MIN_NUMBER))+ MIN_NUMBER);
```

Comment: thank you, but the generated number's last 3-digits are still zeros. Some outputs using your approach, `687008666691635000`, `322464880868778000`, `8823481009216000`, `3935643560572000`

Comment: @micheller First of all, I forgot to add `MIN_NUMBER` to the result, which ensures the output is not too small. That said, I don't outputs ending in zerose.

Answer (score 2):

Strange, I cannot reproduce your problem. Looks like the JVM's random number generation is flawed? You can try [SecureRandom](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/SecureRandom.html) instead of Random.

By the way, I just wanted to note that the `Math.random() * (max - min) + min` pattern does not result in uniform distributed (though it comes close).

You can try out Apache Commons: [RandomDataGenerator](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/random/RandomDataGenerator.html). 
It has an `nextLong(long lower, long upper)` implementation.

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/random/RandomDataGenerator.html